# ¿Cómo cargar jpanel dentro de otro jpanel al mandar evento con boton desde un 3er jpanel?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, jpanel, events

Tengo un frame  con 1 menu bar y 1 jpanel (panelPrincipal) en el cual van cargando jpanelform según la selección del menú bar para ello realizo panelPrincipal.removeAll y repaint del jpanelform seleccionado (Hasta este punto no tengo problemas),
uno de los jpanelform(jpanelProduccion) me carga los datos en un jtable desde una consulta de la base de datos sql server el cual al dar doble clic a una de las filas me lleva a otro jframe(modificarDatos) para actualizar los datos; la razón por el que modificarDatos es un jframe se debe a que uno de sus campos jtextField(txtPeriodo) me abre un  jdialog ( que adentro tiene un jtable y 1 jtextfield que va filtrando el jatable) al dar doble clic el item seleccionado carga el dato en txtPeriodo.
Estoy tratando de realizar que al dar clic en el boton guardar del jframe(modificarDatos), el panelPrincipal cargue el jpanelform (jpanelProduccion) con los datos actualizados.
Espero haber explicado el problema correctamente, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale te entiendo, lo que puedes hacer y te recomiendo mucho la verdad  es leer sobre la interfaz "PropertyChangeListener" te dejo el link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html

En pocas palabras es como escuchar los eventos de los paneles, y tu puedes  hacer que levantes un evento y tu panel lo escuche y al saber el nombre del evento (tu decides su nombre) controlas la acción, algo así como escuchar y lanzar.

Comment: Gracias Ramses, ya pude solucionarlo